# Error when sending SMS to phone number in .AAB or .APK file (Firebase)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

I have an application where I use phone authentication in Firebase (phone number as login, SMS is sent for confirmation). A debugged working version is ready, I submitted it for review by the Google Store, it was accepted. But I decided to run "closed testing" and installed the application.

I opened a screen where you need to enter a phone number, i added number and click "sign in".

I have en ERROR! I use numbers from different countries, but no results,

I started searching and checking, all permissions are specified, everything is enabled in the Firebase options.

**Important!**

My project is running in VS Code, I connect a real device and install the final build on it (which was submitted for review in .AAB format in the Google Store).

On a real device, I open the screen, enter the phone number and SMS comes to the phone number. I tried to look for the problem, but did not understand what the reason is. I created an APK and sent it to my friend, he installed it on his device and similarly received an error immediately after entering the phone in the field.

I created files in Android Studio and VS Code but no results.
Signed files accepted by Google Store support

I prepare AAB files according to documentation. I created APK and tried, same error. I looked in "Google's Console Cloud" and saw them in the "Identity Toolkit API".

I don't understand why it doesn't work in APK or AAB, but on a connected device and installing directly, it's fine.

I am attaching my code, where the functions responsible for sending the code and confirming the phone are indicated

In both functions I pre-send phone numbers, it is in the correct format "+1650*******" without extra characters.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../generated/locale_keys.g.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../utils/showOTPDialog.dart';
import '../utils/showSnackBar.dart';

Future<void> phoneSignInClient(
    BuildContext context,
    String _phoneClientFinal,
  ) async {
    TextEditingController codeController = TextEditingController();

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: _phoneClientFinal,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        codeController.text = credential.smsCode.toString();
        await _auth.currentUser!.reload();
        if (_auth.currentUser == null) {
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        }
      },
      verificationFailed: (e) {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  LocaleKeys.incorrect_phone.tr(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
      codeSent: ((String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        showOTPDialog(
          codeController: codeController,
          context: context,
          onPressed: () async {
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId: verificationId,
              smsCode: codeController.text.trim(),
            );

            try {
              await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/client');
            } catch (e) {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        LocaleKeys.wrong_code.tr(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }

          
          },
        );
      }),
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        // Auto-resolution timed out...
      },
    );
  }

Future<void> phoneSignInCompany(
    BuildContext context,
    String _phoneCompanyFinal,
  ) async {
    TextEditingController codeController = TextEditingController();
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: _phoneCompanyFinal,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        codeController.text = credential.smsCode.toString();
        await _auth.currentUser!.reload();
        if (_auth.currentUser == null) {
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        }
      },
      verificationFailed: (e) {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  LocaleKeys.incorrect_phone.tr(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
      codeSent: ((String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        showOTPDialog(
          codeController: codeController,
          context: context,
          onPressed: () async {
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId: verificationId,
              smsCode: codeController.text.trim(),
            );

            try {
              await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
              
            } catch (e) {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        LocaleKeys.wrong_code.tr(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }),
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        // Auto-resolution timed out...
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added ``SHA`` keys into firebase console? , or you can by running on your app into ``--release`` mode

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I looked in more detail about SHA. After creating the .ABB, Google signs the file. In the project options in Firebase, you must specify SHA1 from google data. 

Info in: Setting - Application Integrity - Application Signatures